# Reregistering for dstar

Tags: d-star

I registered on K0HAM many years ago as K0WKM.  It appears that it was successfully changed later to my current call K0AX.  My registration is apparently still on the us trust server but the checking services report there is some sort of error about a space.  K0HAM no longer has a dstar repeater and there is no way from their website to contact. There are apparently no dstar repeaters in the Kansas City area for me to contact.  How can I either fix my registration or cancel it to re register somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

This should help http://dstargateway.org/D-Star_Registration.html

"... Should you have any problems with registration, send email to AA4RC@ARRL.NET and include your name, callsign, and problem description. "

Comment: If your registration is mangled, then Don's right, you'll need to get an administrator to either fix the registration for the entire US trust system, or delete the registration and then have your local D-STAR gateway administrator re-register you.

Comment: That's Robin, isn't it?  I should have thought of him first.  Thanks.